# How to get list of specific child instances from list of parent instances?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The answer is probably very simple but I could not find it myself.

My classes are as follows

```
public class Element
{
}

public class LineElement : Element
{
}

public class CircleElement : Element
{
}
```

In my code I want to achieve this:

```
List<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();

List<LineElement> Lines = Elements.Where( x=> ..........).ToList();
```

What is the way to achieve this without defining a type specifying property (like string `type`) in my child classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need [OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
List<LineElement> Lines = Elements.OfType<LineElement>.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I was going to use Linq as I showed in my question, Is GetType() what I am looking for? ex: x=> x.GetType() == oftype(LineElement) . Or it will return type of Parent class?

Comment: What you're thinking of is `x => x.GetType() == typeof(LineElement)`, but this different from doing `.OfType()` as the former will only get elements of type `LineElement` while the later will also get any subclasses of `LineElement` too.

Comment: `OfType` is also linq! you can use `Where(x=> x is LineElement)`